# hyperledger fabric: cannot enroll more than one user

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I am developing a hyperledger fabric app based on balance-transfer example, which is currently stuck in registering user. I have some organizations, e.g. bank, caseManager... At first it was the absence of affiliation(of some orgs I added) that throws error messages, but then after I have added some lines to create affiliation, some strange messages appear.... I am only allowed to enroll one user. If I try to enroll more, it will show this:

```
[ERROR] Helper - Failed to get registered user: userABC with error: Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{"code":0,"message":"2 rows were affected when updating the state of identity userABC"}]]
```

I have been searching for so long and still cannot find the answer for this. Please help!!!

Code:

```
var registerUser = async function (params) {
try {
    var userOrg = params.userOrg;
    var org = params.org;
    var username = params.username;

    var client = await getClientForOrg(userOrg, username, true);

    logger.debug('Successfully initialized the credential stores');

    var user = await client.getUserContext(username, true);

    if (user && user.isEnrolled()) {

        logger.info('Successfully loaded member from persistence');

    } else {

        logger.info('User %s was not enrolled, so we will need an admin user object to register', username);

        var admins = hfc.getConfigSetting('admins');
        let adminUserObj = await client.setUserContext({ username: admins[0].username, password: admins[0].secret });

        let caClient = client.getCertificateAuthority();
        let affiliationService = caClient.newAffiliationService();

        console.log("passed 1");

        let registeredAffiliations = await affiliationService.getAll(adminUserObj);

        console.log("passed 2");

        if (!registeredAffiliations.result.affiliations.some(
            x => x.name == org)) {
            let affiliation = org + '.department1';
            await affiliationService.create({
                name: affiliation,
                force: true
            }, adminUserObj);
        }

        console.log("passed 3");

        let secret = await caClient.register({
            enrollmentID: username,
            role: 'user',
            affiliation: org + '.department1'
        }, adminUserObj);

        console.log("passed 4");
        logger.debug('Successfully got the secret for user %s: %s', username, secret);

        user = await client.setUserContext({ username: username, password: secret });
        user.setRoles(['client']);
        user._enrollmentSecret = secret.toString();
        user = await client.setUserContext(user);

        logger.debug('Successfully enrolled username %s and setUserContext on the client object', username);
    }

    if (user && user.isEnrolled) {

        var response = {
            success: true,
            secret: user._enrollmentSecret,
            message: username + ' enrolled Successfully in ' + userOrg,
        };

        console.log(response);

        return response;

    } else {

        throw new Error('User was not enrolled ');

    }
} catch (error) {

    logger.error('Failed to get registered user: %s with error: %s', username, error.toString());
    return 'failed: ' + error.toString();

}
```

};

One thing I noticed is that if the enrollment/register is not going to be successful, the debug lines "passed 2" and "passed 3" will be printed twice in the console. So the lines around there will be run more than once in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt read/understand all of the code but what could be helpful is logging what happens on the other side. So have a look in the ca's log and see what fails there. Could also be only a spelling issue.